# How to install Doxygen as a tool in a Jenkinsfile declarative pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, doxygen

I have this in my `Jenkinsfile`:

```
tools {
    hudson.plugins.doxygen.DoxygenInstallation "doxygen-1.8.16"
}
```

which results in this error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 7: unexpected token: doxygen-1.8.16 @ line 7, column 52.
   s.doxygen.DoxygenInstallation "doxygen-1
                                 ^

1 error

    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.failIfErrors(ErrorCollector.java:310)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addFatalError(ErrorCollector.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:120)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ErrorCollector.addError(ErrorCollector.java:132)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.addError(SourceUnit.java:350)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.transformCSTIntoAST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.antlr.AntlrParserPlugin.parseCST(AntlrParserPlugin.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.SourceUnit.parse(SourceUnit.java:234)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$1.call(CompilationUnit.java:168)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:943)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:605)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:581)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:558)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:298)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:268)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:688)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:700)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.doParse(CpsGroovyShell.java:142)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsGroovyShell.reparse(CpsGroovyShell.java:127)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.parseScript(CpsFlowExecution.java:561)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution.start(CpsFlowExecution.java:522)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowRun.run(WorkflowRun.java:327)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

I have added `doxygen-1.8.16` as a Doxygen Installation in the Global Tool Configuration of Jenkins.

What is the correct way of adding Doxygen as a tool in a `Jenkinsfile`?

Comment: It is not strange that version 1.8.6 of Doxygen is used, this is the version that our dev team uses internally and that's not really my tree to bark up against. Do I understand you correctly if I should change the value so that it does no longer contains a dot?

Comment: I assume the installation stuff comes also fro your dev team so I would address them about the problem you have and to stay with your terminology I would bark loud against the dev team about the old version of doxygen they use / propose (especially from your position as QA Engineer).

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. The current implementation is in a shell script that only works on Windows, and I want to move to a Declarative Pipeline that is platform independent.

Comment: `1.8.6` is a typo, it's actually `1.8.16`. That doesn't change the rest of my question.

Comment: I decided to drop this, manually install Doxygen on the nodes, set a variable `DOXYGEN_BIN` pointing to the installed Doxygen binary on that node, and then use `sh "${DOXYGEN_BIN}"` in my pipeline.